# Can't Read Files using External Tables or Write Files using UTL_FILE using PL/SQL

Tags: linux, database, oracle, unix, plsql

I have an issue wherein I can't Read a simple File using an External Table, nor can I write files using `UTL_FILE`. I think this has something to do with the permissions but I can't figure it out.

I confirmed that `APPS` and `PUBLIC` have the sufficient privileges:

```
select GRANTEE, privilege from all_tab_privs
where  table_name = 'EXT_TAB_DATA';

GRANTEE PRIVILEGE
------- --------
APPS    WRITE
APPS    READ
APPS    EXECUTE
PUBLIC  WRITE
PUBLIC  READ
PUBLIC  EXECUTE
```

And I also confirmed that the actual Directory is defined:

```
select * from all_directories
where  directory_name = 'EXT_TAB_DATA';

OWNER   DIRECTORY_NAME  DIRECTORY_PATH              ORIGIN_CON_ID
------  --------------  --------------------------  -----------------
SYS     EXT_TAB_DATA    /u01/app/oracle/DEV/SAMPLE  0
```

Below is the privileges of the directory `/u01/app/oracle/DEV/SAMPLE`

```
[appldev-run ~]$ ls -l /u01/app/oracle/DEV
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 appldev appldev 6473 Jun 19 15:10 EBSapps.env
drwxr-xr-x 5 appldev appldev 4096 Jun  4 10:13 fs1
drwxr-xr-x 5 appldev appldev 4096 Jun  7 16:26 fs2
drwxr-xr-x 4 appldev appldev 4096 May 22 12:32 fs_ne
-rw------- 1 root    root       0 Sep 18  2018 nohup.out
drwxrwxrwx 2 oracle  appldev 4096 Jun 25 02:31 SAMPLE
```

When I try to write a simple `UTL_FILE` command below:

```
declare 
  fHandle  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
begin
  fHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('EXT_TAB_DATA', 'test_file', 'w');

  UTL_FILE.PUT(fHandle, 'This is the first line');
  UTL_FILE.PUT(fHandle, 'This is the second line');
  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fHandle, 'This is the third line');

  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fHandle);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception: SQLCODE=' || SQLCODE || '  SQLERRM=' || SQLERRM);
    RAISE;
end;
/
```

it results into an error like below:

```
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at line 14
29283. 00000 -  "invalid file operation"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to read from a file or directory that does
           not exist, or file or directory access was denied by the
           operating system.
*Action:   Verify file and directory access privileges on the file system,
           and if reading, verify that the file exists.
```

And I even tried reading from an External Table:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_ext
( sample1 varchar(10) )
organization external (
  default directory EXT_TAB_DATA
  location ('test.txt')
  );
/

select  *
from    sample_ext;  
/
```

It results into an error below:

```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-04001: error opening file /u01/app/oracle/DEV/SAMPLE/SAMPLE_EXT_62883.log
29913. 00000 -  "error in executing %s callout"
*Cause:    The execution of the specified callout caused an error.
*Action:   Examine the error messages take appropriate action.
```

I confirmed that the file is there and has data:

```
[appldev-run@hamlfinappdev ~]$ cd /u01/app/oracle/DEV/SAMPLE
[appldev-run@hamlfinappdev ~]$ cat test.txt
1
1
1
1
[appldev-run@hamlfinappdev ~]$
```

What do I need to do to read and write to this directory?

Database Version is as Follows:

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    12.1.0.2.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
```

Comment: You're looking at the operating system directories on the DB server, right, not on a client box? The path suggests that's likely to be the case but not clear. And the directory and files exist on all nodes? Can the `oracle` user (not `appldev-run`) get to the OS directories manually - i.e. permissions are right on parent directories too? And are you connected to CDB or PDB when you try to access the directory object?

Comment: @AlexPoole, Yes, i'm looking at the OS directories from the DB. I'm not sure if the directory and file exists on all nodes. I'm not sure if the `Oracle` user has access to them, I unfortunately don't have the credentials to that user. I'm not sure what CDB and PDB means. Apologies.

Comment: @APC, yes, it runs under APPS. and APPS has READ, WRITE and EXECUTE privileges to the said External Table. As for the `UTL_FILE`, I tested both `test.txt` and `test_file`, and it still won't work.

Comment: I presume you misunderstood Alex's question. You should have those files in the database server's directories and not the client machine's file system. It doesn't mean anything if  you're  "*looking at the OS directories from the DB*".  Identify the hostname of the database server first and check there for the files.

Comment: My guess would be that the `oracle` OS user lacks write privileges on `/u01/app/oracle/DEV/SAMPLE` (although it seems slightly odd). You'll need help from a unix sysadmin to resolve this.

Comment: run `ls -l /u01/app/oracle/DEV/SAMPLE/test.txt`

Comment: @DmitryDemin, this is the result of that command: `-rwxrwxrwx 1 appldev appldev 8 Jun 25 03:06 /u01/app/oracle/DEV/SAMPLE/test.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give all the rights to the directory `chmod 755 DEV` or change the owner of the directory `chown oracle:appdev DEV`.
I repeated the situation and got the same error.
I created a test environment.

user root

```
esmd:/opt/oracle # ls -l |grep DEV
drwxrwx--- 3 appdev appdev    4096 2019-06-25 07:17 DEV
esmd:/opt/oracle/DEV # ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 2 oracle dba 4096 2019-06-25 07:22 SAMPLE

esmd:/opt/oracle # cd DEV/SAMPLE/
esmd:/opt/oracle/DEV/SAMPLE # ls -l

total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba 8 2019-06-25 07:14 test.txt
```

user oracle

```
oracle@esmd:~> more /opt/oracle/DEV/SAMPLE/test.txt
/opt/oracle/DEV/SAMPLE/test.txt: Permission denied
```

user appdev

```
oracle@esmd:~> su appdev
Password:
appdev@esmd:/opt/oracle> ls -l /opt/oracle/DEV/SAMPLE/test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle dba 8 2019-06-25 07:14 /opt/oracle/DEV/SAMPLE/test.txt
```

DB user  system

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY EXT_TAB_DATA AS '/opt/oracle/DEV/SAMPLE';

CREATE TABLE sample_ext
( sample1 varchar(10) )
organization external (
  default directory EXT_TAB_DATA
  location ('test.txt')
  );
select  *
from    sample_ext;  


07:34:14  line 1: ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
07:34:14  ORA-29400: data cartridge error
07:34:14  error opening file /opt/oracle/DEV/SAMPLE/SAMPLE_EXT_4977.log
```

I changed dir DEV `chmod 757 DEV` and All works!

```
appdev@esmd:/opt/oracle> ls -l /opt/oracle |grep DEV
drwxrwx--- 3 appdev appdev   4096 2019-06-25 07:17 DEV
appdev@esmd:/opt/oracle> chmod 775 DEV
appdev@esmd:/opt/oracle> ls -l /opt/oracle |grep DEV
drwxrwxr-x 3 appdev appdev   4096 2019-06-25 07:17 DEV
select  *
from    sample_ext; 
SAMPLE1                                
---------------- 
1                
1                
1                
1
```

I changed dir DEV `chmod 775 DEV or  chown oracle:appdev DEV` and All works!

```
   oracle@esmd:~> su
Password:

esmd:/opt/oracle # ls -l |grep DEV
drwxrwxr-x 3 appdev appdev    4096 2019-06-25 07:17 DEV
esmd:/opt/oracle # chown oracle:appdev DEV
esmd:/opt/oracle # ls -l |grep DEV
drwxrwxr-x 3 oracle appdev    4096 2019-06-25 07:17 DEV
esmd:/opt/oracle # chmod 770 DEV
esmd:/opt/oracle # ls -l |grep DEV
drwxrwx--- 3 oracle appdev    4096 2019-06-25 07:17 DEV
esmd:/opt/oracle #



select  *
    from    sample_ext; 
    SAMPLE1                                
    ---------------- 
    1                
    1                
    1                
    1
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to resolve this with the help of our DBA. He provided the necessary grants and permissions to the directory. :)